# How can I display a more informative error message on mistyped ant targets?

Tags: ant

When one of our developers mistypes an unrecognised ant target name the result is an unfriendly error message such as:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "foo" does not exist in the project "bar".
```

What I would prefer is that it instead run a target that displays the list of available targets. Is there a way to capture the ant error message and instead run another target, or some kind of custom error message?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty *user friendly*. It clearly states that the specified target doesn't exist in the build.xml file. Maybe a non-technical user would fret with a terse *error* message. (What's a target? What's project "bar"?) But, a programmer should be technical enough to read the message and realize their error.

Developers can display all *external* targets via the `ant --projecthelp` command. That can be abbreviated as `ant -p`.

You can help the process by adding `description` parameters to valid targets that the developer can use. If a single target in your `build.xml` has a `description` parameter, `ant --projecthelp` will only display the targets with a `description` parameter.

You can also add a `<description>` task to the top of your `build.xml` file to display information about the project. Here's a simple example:

```
<project name="Fubar" default="foo">

    <description>
        Project Fubar is a highly secret project that you shouldn't know
        anything about. If you have read this, you've violated national
        security guidelines and must be terminated with extreme finality.
        Hey, it hurts me more than  it hurts you.
    </description>

    <target name="foo"
        description="Runs target &quot;foo&quot;"/>

    <target name="fu"/>     <!-- Internal target No description -->

    <target name="bar"
        description="Runs target &quot;bar&quot;"/>
</project>
```

And here's my `ant -p` output:

```
$ ant --projecthelp
Buildfile: build.xml

        Project Fubar is a highly secret project that you shouldn't know
        anything about. If you have read this, you've violated national
        security guidelines and must be terminated with extreme finality.
        Hey, it hurts me more than  it hurts you.

Main targets:

 bar  Runs target "bar"
 foo  Runs target "foo"
Default target: foo
$
```

Notice I have three targets in my `build.xml`, but target `fu` was not mentioned because it is an internal target only.

Answer (score 1):

1. The [Trycatch](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/trycatch.html) task of Ant-contrib could be useful in this case
2. Customise a [Listener](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) of the Ant API

Answer (score 0):

`ant -p` will display a list of targets in your `build.xml` file. Is that good enough?